# Multiply list by float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to multiply each element in list by a float?

```
list2 = [[348105.6589221008, -1126283.2297975265, -0.0], [366317.0251743915, -1122591.9721268031, -0.0]]

result = [x * 1.1 for x in list2]
```

Comment: `result = [[x * 1.1 for x in inner] for inner in list 2]` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = [[x * 1.1 for x in sublist] for sublist in list2]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to let `numpy` do the work:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(list2) * 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [[x * 1.1 for x in y] for y in list2]
```

Comment: how does this not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake during the review, it wasn't the most appropriate comment. Already fixed. In fact **it does provide an answer to this question** and looking at the timestamps, it even looks like you were actually the first one to provide the correct solution in this thread so it deserves recognition. But anyway... it was qualified as **low quality** answer and was subject to review. Additionally it already attracted 2 downvotes. To avoid that in future: 1. try not to post code-only answers, without a word of explanation. 2. [Format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I agree with @mario. your only mistake was to not format your code properly, but your answer deserved to be accepted since you were first.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.